# Rails Model Association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a basic association...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

however, in rails console, whenever I create a member object, there is no user_id field, just the rest of the fields show up. I have no idea why it isn't working and I've tried for about an hour now. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Type `Member` on rails console and hit enter it should show `user_id` field. If not then either you `forgot` to run `migration` or `user_id` field is missing inside table itself.

Comment: you don't have to add the user_id field to any migrations right? i thought the model association did it for you

Comment: Model associations don't automatically add database migrations. You still need to add a migration to add the user_id column to the members table.